Fiber product of topological spaces and relation between maps
This problem is from Manetti's Topology, (problem 3.58, 2nd edition).
Suppose we are given three topological spaces $P,Q,Z$, two continuous maps $f:P\rightarrow Z$ and $g:Q\rightarrow Z$, and suppose $p:P\times Q\rightarrow P$,  $q:P\times Q\rightarrow Q$ are the projection maps. We consider the fiber product by
$$P\times_Z Q=\{(x,y)\in P\times Q:f(x)=g(y)\}.$$
Problem 3.58 asks the reader to show that if $f$ is an open map then $q|_{P\times_Z Q}:P\times_Z Q\rightarrow Q$ is an open map.
$p$ and $q$ are open maps when we consider their domains to be $P\times Q$ but it is not clear to me how $q's$ restriction on $P\times_Z Q$ can be open. If we consider an open set $V\subset P\times_Z Q$, we find an open set $W\subset P\times Q$ such that $V= (P\times_Z Q)\cap W$. Even though $f\circ p(W)$ is open, the same can not be said about $f\circ p(V)$.  Also, $q(V)\subset g^{-1}(f\circ p(V))\subset g^{-1}(f\circ p(W))$. This is where I'm stuck.
Any idea will be appreciated.
Thank you.

This question has been answered in Is the pullback of a *not necessarily continuous* open map along a continuous map open? as well as Evaluation of a pullback (on an open map). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
